# PCRE matching a url with or without args

Tags: regex, pcre

Say a given URL of a JS/CSS file will sometimes ends with '?v=xyz' or such.

How do I capture both cases in PCRE, that is, for

```
"/my/path/lib.js"
```

The following

```
"\.[js|css]$"
```

Works just fine. And I would like to include cases such as:

```
"/my/path/lib.js?v=1.4"
```

and

```
"/my/path/style.css?v=3"
```

I am using Lua-5.1 PCRE lib

```
> rex_pcre = require "rex_pcre"
> return rex_pcre.find("/my/path/jquery.css", "\.(?:js|css)(?:$|\?)")
stdin:1: nothing to repeat (pattern offset: 17)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'find'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
\.(?:js|css)(?:$|\?)
```

Note that `[js|css]` is not what you think it is. It's a character class and it matches one of the characters of `cjs|`, you want a group: `(?:js|css)`.

Comment: Tried this and such, and get error "nothing to repeat", example added

Comment: @TzuryBarYochay, how did you use it? I don't see anything wrong with the expression. Make sure you quote it properly. For example you may need to escape all the backslashes, use \\ instead of \

Comment: @TzuryBarYochay, use `"\\.(?:js|css)(?:$|\\?)"`